# Em desenvolvimento Code First como faço relacionar a tabela AspNetUsers com outras tabela

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para imobiliária e preciso relacionar a Tabela **AspNetUsers** com as tabelas que o sistema terá e **com cardinalidade um para muitos**, isto quero para que o sistema possa me passar relatórios de quem efetuou funcionalidades de cadastro e entre outras funcionalidades executadas dia a dia no sistema.

Caso alguém tenha um tipo de controle melhor pode me indicar, agradeço muito, mas mesmo assim passe a solução para esta minha dúvida, que pode não ser uma das melhores e que pode resolver em partes.

**Uma das tabelas que quero ter o controle de qual usuário que realizou o cadastro é a Tabela Proprietário.**

```
public class Proprietario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
    public string Rg { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Celular { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não deu para entender muito o que você precisa, uma relação de **1/M** é feita com o ;

```
public virtual ICollection<SuaClasse> SuaClasse{ get; set; }
```

na tabela que tem a relação **1/M**

Acredito que seria no seu caso.

```
publuc class AspNetUsers
{
   // ...
   public virtual ICollection<Proprietario> Proprietario{ get; set; }
}

public class Proprietario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
    public string Rg { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Celular { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: é o seguinte, quando criamos uma aplicação Asp.Net MVC temos a opção Change Authentication, com a opção Individual User Account selecionada, com isto a aplicação fica com a funcionalidade de login de usuário, então o que quero, e realizar o relacionamento do usuário logado com a tabela Proprietário, pois o usuário poderá cadastrar Vários Proprietários, Entendeu ?

Answer (score 0):

Como relacionar as suas entidades já foi respondido, mas há outro modo de fazer isso sem relaciona-las:
Quando o seu usuário fizer login você cria uma classe UsuarioLogado com a propriedade aspNetUserId e grava num authCookie. Então cada vez que você precisar do Id do usuário você lê o cookie e preenche o objeto UsuarioLogado. É outro modo de se fazer isso, não estou dizendo que é o melhor...

No seu Login:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var usuario = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

                var usuarioLogado = new UsuarioLogado
                {
                    AspNetUserId = usuario.Id,
                    // outros dados que quiser
                };

                //cria cookie de autenticação
                _httpContext.SetAuthCookie(_dataProtectionProvider, model.RememberMe, usuarioLogado);
```

Mas e depois como ler o cookie?
O jeito menos repetitivo é criar uma controller para fazer isso por você:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;

    public BaseController(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
    {
        _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
    }

    public UsuarioLogado UsuarioLogado { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }

        var httpContext = Request.HttpContext;

        try {
            var usuario = httpContext.GetAuthCookieData<UsuarioLogado>(_dataProtectionProvider);

            UsuarioLogado = usuario;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e) {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Account/?erro=1");
        }
    }
}
```

E então quando você precisar utilizar o usuário logado na sua controller, você faz a controller herdar da baseController:

```
[Route("api/Teste")]
public class ApiTesteController : BaseController
{

  // aqui você pode chamar: UsuarioLogado.AspNetUserId
```

OBS: Você quer fazer relatórios, desse modo você perde o relacionamento e a utilização de propriedades de navegação(virtuais) mas você pode facilmente fazer a consulta e trazer os dados que quer. Se estiver usando entityFramework:

```
 var proprietarios = (context ou repositorio de proprietario).Where(x => x.UsuarioId == (usuario logado ou qualquer outro));
```